# How can i skin flex 4 DataGrid component?

Tags: flash, flex4, flex4.5

I customize header, separator, line, background etc.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the SDK folder of your project navigate to spark.swc>spark>skins>spark>DataGridSkin.  Create a new file in its image, but modified to your liking and supply it as the skin property of your dataGrid.

Hope that helps